# Como "lançar" uma nova linguagem de programação

Tags: design-de-linguagem

Sempre tive interesse em saber como era o lado obscuro das linguagens ,como funcionavam e funcionam ,como elas são por dentro ,e agora que sei estou criando a minha próprio bem básica ,por eu não ter nô mínimo um computador ,ela está sendo criada em JavaScript ,não é a melhor escolha para fazer o que já estou fazendo mas "se não tem tu vai tu mesmo".

Por estes dias estava pensando ,e se eu quiser lançar essa minha linguagem ,para que além de mim outras pessoas também possam usa-la. Então basicamente minha dúvida é como "lançar" minha linguagem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um projeto que começa com uma pessoa, a melhor forma é colocar como projeto aberto, e tentar juntar uma comunidade.

Você cria um repositório no GitHub para o seu projeto de linguagem - ponha o código, e a documentação: a documentação deve ser bem completa, de justificativa, até a especificação da linguagem em si, sem se preocupar com o código, e por fim, a documentação do seu código.

Claro que GitHub é só o sistema mais usado - mas de qualquer forma é importante que seja de código aberto e num repositório público - o serviço pode ser o bitbucket, uma instância de gitlab, etc...

Agora, as linguagens criadas recentemente que tiveram um grande alcance relativamente rápido tem uma coisa em comum: todas foram criadas por mega-corporações multibilionárias - go, kotlin, swift - por exemplo. É um outro tipo de lançamento, quando você tem a possibilide de empregar dezenas de profissionais em tempo integral pra criar sua linguagem - inclusive o time de marketing para criar campanhas de divulgação.

Um fator importante é se seu projeto vai ter alguma inovação de fato - preencher um nicho que não existe no espectro de linguagens, ou se o objetivo é só mais didático: para seu aprendizado e de quem se envolver no projeto.  Há linguagens muito boas na primeira categoria caírem no esquecimento, mesmo depois de alguma tração inicial. Ou você já ouviu falar de "Boo", uma linguagem estaticamente tipada com a sintaxe baseada em Python que roda na VM do .net? Na segunda categoria, o projeto vai, ao menos nos meses iniciais, ficar restrito a um círculo pequeno de usuários de qualquer forma.